# let a webService start a process in jBPM 5.4

Tags: java, web-services, jboss, jbpm

I want to write a webservice (SOAP based) that runs a bpmn2 process in asynch manner.
So for instance you call http://foo.bar.com/ServiceSOAP/ActionStart, pass in SOAP message with full bpmn process name and a map of parameters, then it should start a process and return immediately.
Process should run ofc in background in separate thread (can have subprocesses etc)

Is there any recommended way to do that? Or maybe somebody done that nicely ?
I'm quite familiar with jbpm demo and starting process from eclipse, but this is a way different than standalone webservice war under jboss.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can simply create a webservice for same. I have done it for REST service so I don't have code sample.

I have my application running on one server and jBPM application running on second server. Methods are exposed as web services in jBPM application and my Java application is using it just like normal web service.

I used LocatTaskService in jBPM to run process.